# Tagit and autocomplete feature

Tags: jquery, tag-it

this is the code :

```
$("#AddFriendToGroup").tagit({
                 autocomplete: { 
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'ChatPageTest.aspx/tagFriendAutocomplete',
                            data: "{'ClientID':'" + $("#UserID").val() + "','ClientName': '" + request.term + "'}",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (data) {
                            },
                            error: function (xhr) {
                                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                        minLength: 2
                    }
                });
```

server side :

```
public static string tagFriendAutocomplete(int ClientID,string ClientName)
{
    string Result = "";
    string query = "select fr.FRIEND_ID,c.[USER_NAME] from clients c inner join friends fr on c.CLIENT_ID=fr.FRIEND_ID and fr.CLIENT_ID=" + ClientID + " and c.[USER_NAME] like '%" + ClientName + "%' ";

    DataTable dt = new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).getQueryResult(query);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    { 
       for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
       {
           Result += dt.Rows[i]["FRIEND_ID"] + "," + dt.Rows[i]["USER_NAME"];
        }
    }

    return Result;
}
```

i am confused i don't know what is the right code to put on ajax success function can anyone help me how can i make the autocomplete feature of tagit work in my case to show the clientName resulted from the ajax call

Answer (score 2):

For get information about using $.ajax() in tagit see [How to get tagSource to work with $.ajax()](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/issues/13#issuecomment-5292344)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually kind of tricky and I don't remember seeing the answer spelled out in the docs.

What I did is the following:

```
$("#[id of tag to attach to]").tagit({
autocomplete: {
    source: function( request, response ) {
        if (acAjax && acAjax.readyState != 4)
            acAjax.abort();

        $("#loading").show();

        acAjax = $.ajax({
            url: [server url],
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                returnedUsers = data;
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item,
                        value: item
                    }
                }));
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                returnedUsers = [];
            },
            complete: function(xhr, status, error) {
                $("#loading").hide();
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2
},
allowSpaces: true,
beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
    if ($.inArray(ui.tagLabel, returnedUsers)==-1)
        return false;
}
});
```

Sorry for the bad formatting. Couple of notes:

1. the success 'response' function--this is a function that tagit understands. I'm not completely sure how it works, but note that with this formatting, you can have the tag print one thing ("label"), and have the value be something else.
2. 'returnedUsers' array allows me to prevent the user from adding a tag not returned by the ajax. This was kind of hard to figure out, so I hope that is helpful to you.

the other options are listed in the docs so I won't go into them. Hope this is helpful to you. Simply pointing at the docs is not helpful--I know!

Comment: that's a great answer but i have one simple question also the responce contain a label and a value wish should be the id of the client if let's say i want to store those id's in a hidden field how can i achieve this ?